# SQL + Pandas in While Loop

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, while-loop

I am running a SQL query and saving the results to a pandas DF. My condition is to obtain at least `N` number of rows. I am using a `while-loop` to run and update the query until the condition is met.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({})
rows = df.shape[0]

# search radius - miles to meters
radius = 1.5*1609

# Between 20 to 30 results in comps set
while rows <= 30:

    # Run query
    query = '''
            select * from schema_name.table1
            where st_distance_sphere(Point({},{}), coords) <= {};
            '''.format(Long, Lat, radius)

    df = pd.read_sql(query, con)

    rows = df.shape[0]

    if rows >= 20:
        break
    else:
        radius = radius * 2
```

Basically, the query is looking for rows that are within the specified radius of the `POINT` coordinates. I'd expect this to return `20-30` rows, however, the result is 100 rows. I am likely missing something here and trying to debug what's going on.

Using a while loop how do I restrict the results to `20-30` rows? The idea is to expand the radius if the rows returned are `<20`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a LIMIT clause to restrict the number of rows returned by the query.

```
select * 
from schema_name.table1 
where st_distance_sphere(Point({},{}), coords) <= {}
LIMIT 30;
```

You can also add an ORDER BY for the distance you are calculating and then get the 30 closest points.